# Массив лямбда-выражений

Tags: c++, массивы, лямбда-выражение

Насколько я знаю, можно создать переменную, инициализированную лямбда-выражением: 
`auto cube=[](int x){return x*x*x;};`

> Вопрос: можно ли создать массив таких переменных(массив лямбда-выражений)? Если да, то как его инициализировать?

Comment: Прикольно, у них тип разный: https://ideone.com/62KzTs